# How do I audit my audit logs in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an audit log which works great in my rails application. What is the best approach to make audits of the audit log. How can I track any changes or prevent them? Basically i am worried about the value of the audit logs if someone can tamper with them. I need to be able to audit my audit logs. And then...... audit the audits of my audit logs, so on so forth into infinity.

So far I have tried adding auditing to my audit logs. But then I run into the issue of those audit logs not being audited if they are removed or modified.

Comment: Making the audits insert-only at the database (or filesystem) level should afford some piece of mind. Periodic (i.e. hourly) deltas or forward-only replication should provide additional piece of mind. At some level the data must be securely guarded (cannot be altered) or must be stored somewhere offsite/immutable (cannot be altered).

Comment: (Although it wouldn't surprise me if there was a clever way to keep some form of rolling HMAC that could detect if such an audit was removed/altered, even if it could not say to what level.)

Comment: I like that idea, because even if the data was altered outside the app via some sort of db call directly the HMAC would be wrong. Especially if the salt / key was stored in the app. Kind of 2 layers of protection. I dont think its the whole solution but a very good idea.